# Install Steam games on a Synology network disk

Tags: debian, steam, synology

Recent Microsoft news have convinced me to switch to Linux.

I have a Synology NAS on which I used to install Steam games (and any applications really), it wasn't too complicated to do on Windows, once the disk was registered with a name, I could install Steam games right away, as for applications I had to add the value 'EnableLinkedConnections' into the registry as explained there : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_files/network-mapped-drives-not-available-on-windows-10/ef955b4b-1103-42db-a00d-cd1520a8e178?page=2

I have Debian 10 with Gnome, I have installed Steam as described there : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-with-steam-play-on-debian-10-buster
And I have mounted my Synology drive as described there (using SBM/CIFS configuration) : https://0ut3r.space/2019/07/23/mount-nas/

On Steam, I click Steam - Settings - Downloads - STEAM LIBRARY FOLDERS - ADD LIBRARY FOLDER - * I select an empty folder on my network disk * - SELECT, and I get this error :

[image]

At this point, Steam has created an empty "steamapps" folder in the folder I previously selected. But when I try to select the same folder again (not deleting the "steamapps" folder) I get another error message, perhaps a more helpful one :

[image]

When it comes to disk management I'm a total newbie on both Windows and Linux. What am I missing ?